# Jquery $.post changes values

Tags: jquery

so basically I have this code :

```
for (i=1;i<=7;i++)
            for (j=1;j<=10;j++)
            {
                    $.post('../core/occupied.php',{table : db , row : i , seat : j},
                    function(result){
                        if (result == "green")
                        {
                            var color_id = "rl"+i+j;
                            alert(color_id);
                            //$("#rl"+i+j).css({"background":"rgba(153,153,153,1)","color":"white"});   
                        }
                    });
            }
```

this code gets executed in a for loop for 70 times, and is returning 3 colors depending on the situation from `occupied.php` , and after that I want to change the color of that id formed by i and j , but after the function gets `result` the `i` and `j` values change without any logic.... for example if `i=1` and `j=2` then I want `id = #rl12` to change color , but they change into some other values.... I cannot explain why... can anyone help me ?

Comment: try to fill a var with current i and j value just before the post and use this var after the request

Comment: I did that... it same result...

Comment: So... `i+j` will do simple arithmetic. Is that what you're after?

Comment: no, I want `i` and `j` values to concatenate and form and id ....

Comment: `"rl"+i+j;` this will add i and j

Comment: to be clear, if `i=1` and `j=2` then ` "rl"+i+j`will result in having `rl12` ... that's what I want to accomplish but after `$.post` gets executed `i` and `j` get some crazy values even higher than `for` loop limits....it's like they don't get recognized inside `$.post`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `post` to new function

```
function postThis(i,j){
  $.post('../core/occupied.php',{table : db , row : i , seat : j},
            function(result){
                if (result == "green")
                {
                    var color_id = "rl"+i+""+j;
                    alert(color_id);
                   //$("#rl"+i+j).css({"background":"rgba(153,153,153,1)","color":"white"});   
                }
            });
}
```

Now call your function this way

```
for (i=1;i<=7;i++){
    for (j=1;j<=10;j++)
    {
           postThis(i,j);      
    }
}
```

Comment: working, incredible, thanks man :), I will vote for this answer in 10 min :)